# Quantidade de retorno Mailchimp no PHP

Tags: php

Bom dia

Estou usando um script para retornar os membros de uma lista no API 3.0 do Mailchimp, usando curl no PHP, mas só retorna 10 membros. Tem alguma opção que eu possa incluir para aumentar essa quantidade? Abaixo um código de como eu estou fazendo a requisição:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://'.$server.'api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'.$listid.'/members/?status=unsubscribed');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('content-type: application/json', 'Authorization: Basic '.$auth));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/2.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_post);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na [documentação oficial](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/) existe a opção `count` que permite especificar o número de registros para ser retornado.

O exemplo abaixo deve funcionar legal (traz 100 registros).

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://'.$server.'api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'.$listid.'/members/?status=unsubscribed&count=100'); // mudei aqui
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('content-type: application/json', 'Authorization: Basic '.$auth));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/2.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_post);
```

Comment: Valeu, funcionou perfeitamente